# Seeking GIS based Customer Relationships Management (CRM) tools?

Tags: software-recommendations

I'm searching for a tool like something around a ***"GIS based Customer Relationships Management Tool"***. The functionality I am looking for is:

1. **collect:** collecting customer related data in several formats like e-mails, postal letter as scans, documents, online-masks and so on..
2. **store:** store these files geographically referenced in a DB
3. **categorize:** attach several attributes over time to these customers like: wishes, needs, historical questions, business category ...
4. **manage by query's:** get reports according to queries via attributes or via geo-tag or via combinations like: "*show all customers that like potatoes and mushrooms living in a buffer distance of 20km around point xy and related documents*".

What are some useful tools meeting my needs to test?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a pure tool built for this, salesforce can do some simple geo stuff, but then a custom CiviCRM (opensource) solution could likely be built out to give you more geo capacity. But really what it sounds like you need is not the pre-determined CRM at all, just a solid database with a flexible data entry UI and the ability to run spatial type queries from any GIS client/server. The questions you have are simple geospatial tasks, so relaly any database with a good data entry front end will work if it's geo-enables- PostGIS would be fine. Heck, you could even do it in a desktop GIS client entirely based on your parameters.